# Mocking ExceptionHandler with Mockito using Spring RestController+ExceptionHandler Annotation

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to JUnit test exception handling of a Spring @RestController.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
```

The exception handling is done in the class ErrorHandler.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
```

I am using Mockito because it is very convenient. But now I have trouble figuring out how to make the ErrorHandler work together with the RestController.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private MyController controller;

   @Mock
   private MyService myService;

   @Spy
   private ErrorHandler errorHandler;
```

As you can see I tried to use @Spy to make the "real" ErrorHandler work with the Controller which has mocks injected.

But it does not work this way.

```
@Test
public void testDoWork_InternalServiceException() {
    MyRequest request = getDefaultRequest();
    Mockito.when(myService.check(request)).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());       
    ResponseEntity<StatusResponse> response = controller.doWork(request);
}
```

If I call the controller's method it of course throws an exception now and the ErrorHandler class is never called.

Is there a way to test exception handling of @RestController classes and additional @ControllerAdvice exception handler classes with Mockito ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: The error handling logic is handled by Spring components, of which you have none. Use a `SpringJUnit4Runner` with an appropriate `MockMvc` instance.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I will use Mockito only for the elementary JUnit tests and SpringJUnit4Runner for the integration tests.